# Dose android offers a subscription Across Multiple Apps?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have two apps that have in-app billing features. I want to add an option to subscribe to a product that the second app will treat it as a subscription too, is it possible to do so with the current implementation of google subscription, because apple offer has [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/offering_a_subscription_across_multiple_apps) feature.

Comment: Not sure about that. But you can do it by managing subscriptions from your servers. Responsibility of Google IAP is to make sure the money is safe, how the app provides functionality is You can keep track of the subscriptions from your server and provide functionality in as many apps you want

Comment: It's not a feature that Apple offers. They call it a feature but it's actually something you have to implement yourself, similar to how you would do it on Android.